# How to create a single object and use values in different events?

Tags: c#

I am creating a program with two forms(register and view).
The view form will read a single record from a table(database), and then you can edit or delete the record. I am creating a class for this program, and for one of the constructors it will get the search ID, First name and last name from the view form and then there is a method which will search through the table for the record(using search ID, OR firstname and lastname) and will assign the variables inside the class, and I want to use THOSE variables for my edit and delete methods, but the problem is when I try to create a public object of the class which would be used across all my events, using 'this' keyword, it says that this doesn't exist in the current context, but whenever I create an object in each event it will recognize 'this' keyword, but I won't be able to use the class variables assigned from the search method. This is my constructor and search method for the class

```
    public ASystem(searchSHD search)
    {
        searchHID = search.searchHID;
        search_FName = search.searchFName;
        search_LName = search.searchLName;
    }
    public String searchHID;
    public String search_FName;
    public String search_LName;
    public String HID;
    public String First_Name;
    public String Full_Name;
    public String query;
    public String Last_Name;
    public String PhoneNum;
    public String Country;
    public String DOB;
    public String Experience;
    public void Search()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection db_connection = new     OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\KAZEM\Documents\Hairsalon\employees.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"))
        {
            if (searchHID == "")
            {
                query = "SELECT * FROM Hairdresser where First_Name = @FName AND Last_Name = @LName";
            }
            else
            {
                query = "SELECT * FROM Hairdresser where HID = @HID";
            }
            using (OleDbCommand db_command = new OleDbCommand(query, db_connection))
            {
                db_command.Parameters.Add("@HID", searchHID);
                db_command.Parameters.Add("@FName", search_FName);
                db_command.Parameters.Add("@LName", search_LName);
                db_connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = db_command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                HID = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                First_Name = reader.GetString(1);
                Last_Name = reader.GetString(2);
                Full_Name = First_Name + " " + Last_Name;
                Country = reader.GetString(4);
                PhoneNum = reader.GetString(5);
                DOB = (Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(3))).ToString();
                Experience = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please point out the exact line the error occurs on and the exact text of the error.

Comment: Show us the code creating an instance of your ASystem object (the one with "this" in it), along with the compile error being generated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own event through creating a class which is derived of EventArgs, that like:

```
    class yourEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public yourEventArgs(object yourValues)
    {
        Value = yourValues;
    }
    //Create your properties like below
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

after that you need to create an eventhandler:

```
public event EventHandler<yourEventArgs> YourEventName;
```

for raising the event you use:

```
if(YourEventName!=null)
{YourEventName(this,new yourEventArgs(yourValue));}
```

then you can add to your eventhandler your method through (the code which should be executed if you raise the event)

```
YourEventName+=((object o,yourEventArgs e)=> {/*-Insert Code here-*/});
//or
YourEventName+=on_yourEvent;
private void on_yourEvent(object o,yourEventArgs e)
{
/*-Insert your Code here- */
}
```

I hope that's what you want.